# Search multiple dictionaries with same keys and different values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I search these dictionaries and display the multiple values for a certain key (inputted by user)?
I want the user to enter the course number they are listed in and output to show room number, instructor, and meeting time.

I cant seem to get my output to display what I want. When I run my programme, I input the course number but the output (ResultList) displays  all the courses and times. Instead I want my output to be in the format as in my example. When I enter a course number I want only the information of that course number to be displayed. Right now all the information for all courses are being displayed. HELP please

*Please note that the dictionaries must remain in the format I've listed*

Code:

```
list1 = {"CS101":"Room 3004", "CS102":"Room 4501", "CS103":"Room 6755", "NT110":"Room 1244", "CM241":"Room 1411"}

list2 = {"CS101":"Haynes", "CS102":"Alvarado", "CS103":"Rich", "NT110":"Burke", "CM241":"Lee"}

list3 = {"CS101":"08:00", "CS102":"09:00", "CS103":"10:00", "NT110":"11:00", "CM241":"13:00"}

ResultList = {k:[ list1[k], list2[k], list3[k] ] for k in list1}

Course = input("Enter Course Number: \n")

if Course == 'CS101' or 'CS102' or 'CS103' or 'NT110' or 'CM241':
    print(ResultList)
else:
    print("Course not Found!")
```

Example:

```
Enter Course Number: 
CS102

CS102
Room 3004
Instructor: Heynes
Meeting time: 08:00
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: What is your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have updated my post to clarify my question. Thank you

Comment: I cant seem to get my output to display what I want. When I run my programme, I input the course number but the output (ResultList) displays  all the courses and times. instead I want my output to be in the format as in my example. When I enter a course number I want only the information of that course number to be displayed. Right now all the information for all courses are being displayed. HELP please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward solution.

```
>>> Course = "CS102"    
>>> if Course in list1.keys() and list2.keys() and list3.keys():
    ...     print("Room {}\nInstructor: {} \nMeeting time: {}".format(list1[Course], list2[Course], list3[Course]))
    ... else:
    ...     print("Course not found!")
    ... 
    Room Room 4501
    Instructor: Alvarado 
    Meeting time: 09:00

>>> Course = "foo"
>>> if Course in list1.keys() and list2.keys() and list3.keys():
...     print("Room {}\nInstructor: {} \nMeeting time: {}".format(list1[Course], list2[Course], list3[Course]))
... else:
...     print("Course not found!")
... 
Course not found!
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! This ran successfully!